# JasperReport : Apply margin to textfield conditionally

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to set a margin-bottom to TextFields based on a condition (let's say : value1 == true).
I haven't found informations about margins applied on textfields.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you know something about conditional styles in Jasper reports?

Below is the sample for your scenario

```
<style name="Style1">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{value1} == true]]></conditionExpression>
        <style>
            <box bottomPadding="10">
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

For the text field use style "Style1".

Hope this should solve your question

Comment: thanks, this conditional style works fine. But I don't know how to increase the space between my textfield or increase the height of my textfield.

Comment: Does "increasing the height" mean whenever the text become larger the height of the text field need to be increased?

Comment: I am displaying  rows of data, I want to increase the space at the bottom of rows conditionally. As rows are displaying textfields I was thinking of increasing the space at the bottom of each textfield of the row. Not sure this way is the best though.

Comment: I have edited my above answer accordingly to include padding at bottom

Comment: I think padding creates a padding in the textfield, so it kind of pushes the value to the top of the textfield, but it doesn't increase the space between the textfield and the textfield of the next row.

Comment: i have added a picture of what I want to get. see the space between the line which starts by 33.7% and the next row

Comment: You cannot dynamically adjust the position of a component in jasper reports. But while rendering the report, jasper report engine dynamically adjust the position of the component based on other components. We cannot manually adjust the position of the component.